# Jersey - The requested resource (Not Found) is not available

Tags: java, jersey, http-status-code-404

It seems that any settings i try it doesn't work to access the methods in class. I keep getting 404 not found.
This is the web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Restful Web Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>restfulexample.status</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Restful Web Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and this the java file inside src/main/java:

```
package restfulexample.status;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("v1/status")
public class V1_status {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String returnTitle(){
    return "Java restful api";
}
}
```

Comment: More information is needed. What's the URL you're using to access your Jersey endpoint? What's the name of your webapplication? And on which server are you deploying your webapplication?

Comment: I'm trying http://localhost:8181/RestfulExample/v1/status.
On http://localhost:8181/RestfulExample/ the index.html it's working. The Project name is RestfulExample. Server: Apache Tomcat

Comment: Have you tried adding some logging into your controller class to check whether it is instantiated at all? And, by the way, any particular reason that you are using outdated Jersey 1.XX?

Comment: check the server logs. I have had similar problems and the cause was Jersey being unable to scan for resources

Answer (score 1):

Could be me, but is `@Path("v1/status")` not missing a slash? So basically `@Path("/v1/status")`.

### Update

Just hit me: your url-pattern in web.xml is missing an asterisk. Change it to:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Restful Web Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: No, it's not that. :(

Comment: Which version of Jersey are you using? Do you see any errors in the logs during start-up of the server or the webapplication?

Comment: I think you're missing an asterisk in your servlet-mapping. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the route is right, I don't know if you put all of the *.jar* files of jersey([jersey2.x](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jaxrs-ri/2.17/jaxrs-ri-2.17.zip)) in to the *lib* folder, because they are departed into three parts under *jersey-ir/*